# ANTLR unit is also an identifier

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to create a LESS parser in ANTLR, and I'm using Twitter Bootstrap's LESS files for testing. I've got it mostly working, but there's one part that's stumping me, and I think it's because I don't completely grok ANTLR.

In [less/mixins.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L319), there is a [mixin declaration](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L319) as follows:

```
.directional(@start-color: #555; @end-color: #333; @deg: 45deg) {
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@deg, @start-color, @end-color); // Safari 5.1-6, Chrome 10+
  background-image: linear-gradient(@deg, @start-color, @end-color); // Standard, IE10, Firefox 16+, Opera 12.10+, Safari 7+, Chrome 26+
}
```

The thing that's hanging up my parser is that there's a variable with the same name as a unit. The `@deg` token, instead of getting parsed as a `variable`, gets parsed as `Asperand unit` instead (because `deg` is a unit). Since this is invalid, the parser quits. I've tried rearranging the order of my declarations in my ANTLR file, but it still won't work.

Subset of my grammar:

```
varAssignment
    : variable w Colon w expr
    ;

expr
    : expr w term w
    | expr w Comma w term w
    | term w
    ;

term
    : variable
    | measurement
    ;

variable
    : Asperand Identifier
    ;

// Insignificant whitespace.
w: (W | Comment)*;

Identifier
    : NameStart NameChar*
    ;

Ampersand: '&';
Asperand:  '@';
Comma:     ',';
Semi:      ';';
Colon:     ':';
Ellipsis:  '...';

OpenBlock:  '{';
CloseBlock: '}';
OpenParen:  '(';
CloseParen: ')';
OpenSquare: '[';
CloseSquare:']';

W: (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f' )+;


number: Number;
Number: Dgt+ | Dgt* '.' Dgt+;

fragment NameChar
    : NameStart
    | Dgt
    ;
fragment NameStart
    : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '-'
    ;
fragment Dgt
    : '0'..'9'
    ;


unit:'%'
    |'px'
    |'em'
    |'ex'
    |'in'
    |'cm'
    |'mm'
    |'pc'
    |'deg'
    |'rad'
    |'grad'
    ;


measurement
    : Number unit?
    ;
```

How would I have to rearrange my declarations so that `@deg` parses as a `variable`, but `45deg` parses as a `measurement`?

I know I could cheat and define `unit: Identifier | '%' ;` but that would be pretty atrocious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redefine your `unit` rule as you described at the end of the question. It's not "cheating". In fact, as long as your resulting grammar is ambiguous, it greatly improves your ability to extend the grammar in the future to accept additional types of units.

You can validate the specific `Identifier` for a unit in a listener or visitor that executes after the initial parse is complete.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was something fundamental about ANTLR that I was misunderstanding... I thought all the validation had to come from the productions themselves. Thanks for showing me the way.